# Finding derivative of integral

Tags: calculus

I know about basic of fundamental theorem of integral calculus but i cannot think of how to go on with this question 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds  =xf'(x)$$ by L' Hospital rule.
Hence $f$ satisfy differential following equation : $$f(x) =xf'(x)$$ hence $$f(x) =Cx$$ but $$2 =C\sqrt{2}$$ thus $C=\sqrt{2}$ and therefore $$f(x) =\sqrt{2} x.$$
So $$f(3) =3\sqrt{2} .$$

Comment: the first step u have written i have not understood . isnt that can be written when uper limit is x and below limit is constant . shouldnt we split the integral